# Как использовать исходники другого maven проекта?

Tags: java, maven

у меня несколько Maven проектов на одном уровне директории. 
Я не хочу весь код дублировать, я хочу подключить другой модуль(проект) и юзать код оттуда.

в новом проекте я указал

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>AutotestsRepo</id>
            <url>file://${basedir}/../../Autotests</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>Autotests</groupId>
        <artifactId>Autotests</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

локально, при дебаггинге, все работает, методы вызываются. 
А при выполнении `mvn clean install` получаю

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project newProject: Could not resolve dependencies for project newProject:newProject:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find Autotests:Autotests:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in http://*******:8081/nexus/content/groups/hosted was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus-hosted has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]`

Как мне подключить так, чтобы не нужно было билдить другой проект в jar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>Autotests</groupId>
        <artifactId>Autotests</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
       <systemPath>${basedir}/../../Autotests/target/Autotests-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar</systemPath>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: А джарник  у вас  в папке`target` без сборки проекта сам появится, да? :)

Comment: @enzo конечно нет ))